# I can't turn off the breadcrumb in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried to uncked some check boxes at the Setting but this breadcrumb keeps appearing over and over. How do I turn it off for sure?

[image: http://makescreen.ru/i/344203f5139aa36b252e172bd333ea.jpg]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you see is not breadcrumbs, it's [Navigation Bar](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigation-bar.html) and it can be disabled from the `View` menu.

Answer (score 0):

And it cam be shown în floating mode using alt+home shortcut.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigation-bar.html

Comment: do you happen to know the Mac equiv to ctrl-home?

Comment: Hi javadba. Unfortunately I mislead you with the incorrect shortcut. The correct one is alt+home.

Comment: In order to know a shortcut I usually do: 1. open settings (Ctrl+Alt+S), 2. type 'keymap', 3.  type 'jump to navigation bar'. I hope this will be of help.